# when rails server start , how to Initialize some my own task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, rack

eg: I wanna run something automatically when start the server
I get a not so clear view about that, is there something about rake?

...
I do remove the stupid example

Comment: Why do you need to seed your database on *every* start? What actual problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I just wanna know how to initialize the app with something more, if I could do this , I could make more things, such as run the test first, if not passed, i got a warning, things like that. I just curious about this.Not some specific problem to slove

Comment: You have been  down voted because your question describes something that really should never be done. Rather than using a badly contrived example you could come back and edit your question with a real world issue that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an initializer file in `config/initializers` folder for example `task_scheduler.rb` and then use Rufus scheduler to run tasks:

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

scheduler.in '4s' do
  autocallprocess_method
end

scheduler.every '1m' do
  autocallprocess_method
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to run a piece of code that in initialises something on server startup, rather than as a rake task/controller action etc? Simplest way is to create a file in config/initializers and put any ruby code in there.

Any file in this folder gets run on server startup.